# If all that existed was a supermassive black hole and yourself would you ever have knowledge of its presence, how could you detect it?

Tags: black-holes, dark-energy

So this question is a two-parter.

To elaborate on the first question, let's say you are 10 light-years away from this black hole and it is the mass of the one in the center of our galaxy.

2nd question:
Now let's say there is a third object and it is another person that is 20 light-years away from the black hole and you are in the middle of the two. You can communicate with this person and measure the distance between each other. Would this new person appear to accelerate away from you as you are feeling a larger effect due to gravitation? What would you attribute this acceleration away from each other as?

Comment: "*What would you attribute this acceleration away from each other as?*" - Dark energy ;)

Comment: Your second question doesn't cover the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell you are in a gravitational field by tidal forces.

Your feet are nearer the black hole than your head. Your feet are accelerated toward it more strongly. Your head is left behind. This stretches you.

For a distant supermassive black hole. The tidal force will be small. But it is still there.

This is exactly the same thing as the 2 person case you talked about. You would attribute it to gravity.

Perhaps if the universe was as empty as you describe, it might be hard to convince yourself that no other explanation exists. But never the less, you do feel evidence of gravity.

Answer (score 0):

You'd know that the black hole is there if you gave yourself a velocity in a direction perpendicular to the black hole.  You would then observe that your motion relative to the other mass would be following a curved path, even an orbit around the central object if you gave yourself enough horizontal velocity to avoid the black holes event horizon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Forward mass-detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_L._Forward#Forward_Mass_Detector) to detect the gravitational field. Basically, it consists of two crossing arms that rotate, enabling detection of gravitational gradients. If you are in free fall you will not notice the main gravitational force, but the tidal components are in principle detectable (in practice I think this will not work at the distances in the problem).

In the second part of the question, you would notice that you are moving away from the other guy at an accelerating rate. You would also notice that photons sent from him would have a smaller redshift than predicted from special relativity, while he would see more redshift from you. The difference at 10 ly is pretty minimal, but it would grow. This asymmetry would hint that the situation is not just you both being separated by (say) cosmological expansion, but that one of you were in a different situation.